# When is WM_PAINT called?

Tags: c++, windows, image, winapi, bmp

When exactly is WM_PAINT called? Im trying to create a dialog based slot machine application, but i've run into a couple of logical issues. My application will consist of:

- "Spin" Button
- Exit Button
- Three BMP images to display the results of the spin(coin/heart/soldier)

How will i show the final result of the spin using the BMP images? Am i correct in using WM_PAINT to attempt to display the images, how will i refresh the screen each time the user presses the spin button to show the new images? I really appreciate the help!

Comment: You can (and should) use `InvalidateRect` to send it indirectly.

Comment: so i should call invalidateRect inside of the 'spin' button? appreciate the help.

Comment: chris is totally right. InvalidateRect will (a) update the invalid (i.e. to-be-painted) region of the window within the window construct, and (b) set the WM_PAINT bit for that window to hot. The next time the message pump is serviced the WM_PAINT will be picked up (if no priority-higher messages are pending, as WM_PAINT is pretty much at the bottom of the ladder). If you want immediate updating, follow InvalidateRect with UpdateWindow to bypass the message pump and send WM_PAINT processing directly to the window proc.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I'm not sure about that advice. A dialog has its own message pump and window proc.

Comment: @MSalters the location of the message pump should not be relevant for this. he has a window region that is marked as invalid (via `InvalidateRect(hwnd,...)`. Firing `UpdateWindow()` should directly hit the proper window proc with the appropriate DC setup and the invalid region-union established (or not, interestingly enough, if the invalid region is empty at the time of the call). So has always been my experience, anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dialog boxes normally use `DefDlgProc` as the window procedure.  You can't handle `WM_PAINT` in your `DialogProc` (it isn't a window procedure).  [You can use your own window procedure with a dialog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/13/55662.aspx) but that's probably more trouble than it's worth.

The simplest way to display a bitmap on a dialog is to use a static control with the `SS_BITMAP` style.

You can change the displayed bitmap by sending the [`STM_SETIMAGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760782%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message to the static control.  The control will take care of repainting itself with the new bitmap.

This is OK if you just want to display the result of a spin, but won't work very well if you want to animate the spinning of the reels.  To handle this you could create your own static control (i.e. a window for each reel) that would display a portion of a reel bitmap.